# CSS: give element same width as "grandparent" element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a supercontainer (fitting screen width, with margins and padding) , which contains a wider container, which in turn contains (sorry for the redundancy) an undetermined (DB-driven) number of left-floated boxes.  It is all part of a Backbone/Underscore template.

I want the boxes to have the same width as the supercontainer, in order to make only one visible at a time (there's a horizontal scroller-function in the Backbone View).  I know I could use jQuery to get the supercontainer's width and apply it to boxes upon rendering, but I would definitely prefer a pure-CSS solution to avoid issues with screen resizing.

To make things clear:

HTML:

```
<div id="supercontainer">
  <div id="wide-container">
    <div class="fun-box"></div>
    <div class="fun-box"></div>
    <div class="fun-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#supercontainer {
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:50px;
}

#wide-container {
  display:table;
}

.fun-box {
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  width: ???; /* something that makes it as wide as the supercontainer */
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why display:table? And how can a child be wider than it's parent?

Comment: width:100%, but display:table will not give you the result you want. Why are you using it?

Comment: "I want the boxes to have the same width as the supercontainer, in order to make only one visible"- each box will have the width  of super container and only one will be visible at a time..?

Comment: @Paulie_D why can't a child be wider than it's parent..? 0___0 ?

Comment: @haxtbh To make the #wide-container as wide as the sum of its children .fun-box's widths (that's working fine if I preset .fun-box to a given width)

Comment: @TJ  Exactly! There will be a horizontal scroller.

Comment: vAha...scrolling. Now it makes sense.Most people try to avooid it but if it's a design choice that's different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `#supercontainer` always has `100%` width of window, you can match it by applying `width: 100vw` for the boxes

```
.fun-box {
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  width: 100vw; 
}
```

> Viewport-percentage lengths defined a length relatively to the size of viewport, that is the visible portion of the document.
>   
>  1vw =1/100th of the width of the viewport

-[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)

Answer (score 0):

You can try making `.fun-box` a third of `#wide-container`'s width, and `#wide-container` three times `#supercontainer`:

```css
#wide-container {
    width: 300%;
}
.fun-box {
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZCb5/)